# When to use sein or ihr?

Tags: possessive-pronoun

I am wondering if there is a rule to know when I have to use the possesive pronoun *sein* or *ihr*.

For instance:

> Er liebt **seine** Frau sehr
>
> Er liebt **ihre** Frau sehr

How does the meaning change by changing the pronoun. About which wife are we talking?

or another example:

> Die Mutter holt **ihren** Sohn vom Kindergarten ab.
>
> The mother takes her son from the kindergarden.

Is it her son or another mother's son?

Comment: "Sein" and "ihr"aren't prepositions, they're pronouns, and possesive pronouns to be specific.

Comment: Was sagt das Wörterbuch?

Comment: Different to French the gender of the pronoun follows the subject, not the object in German. May that be your issue here?

Comment: @Takkat Actually the pronoun "follows" *both* subject *and* object! The ending is feminine (-e, not -en), because the object of love is the wife, not the husband (as in French "son/sa"), the "beginning" changes with the gender of the subject (sein-/ihr-). So what you probably meant to say was that the third person pronoun differs with the gender of the subject, unlike in French, where there is only one for both genders of subject.

Comment: Why does this type of question keep leaving the close vote review queue?

Comment: @Jan Vielleicht, weil es außer mir noch andere [so sehen](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/a/1195/9091).

Comment: Reopen it because Takkat is right!

Comment: The example in Marine1's comment is better than the one in the question above:  "Die Mutter holt ihren Sohn vom Kindergarten ab. (=The mother takes her son from the kindergarden.)" - Is it her son or another mother's son?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its the same as in English:

1. The pronoun refers to the sentences subject, which is male:

   > Walter hat gerade Maria geheiratet.
   >   **Er** *(Walter)* **liebt *seine*** *(eigene)* **Frau sehr.**
   >
   > Walter just has married Maria.
   >   **He** *(Walter)* **loves *his*** *(own)* **wife very much.**

   Here the pronoun refers to »er« (»he«) which is the subject of the sentence. Since er/he is male, the pronoun also has to be male.
2. The pronoun refers to something outside the sentence, which is male:

   > Michael ist mit Claudia verheiratet, aber auch Markus liebt Claudia. Markus ist Michaels bester Freund.
   >   **Er** *(Markus)* **liebt *seine*** *(Michaels)* **Frau sehr.**
   >
   > Michael is married to Claudia, but also Markus loves Claudia. Markus is Michaels best friend.
   >   **He** *(Markus)* **loves *his*** *(Michaels)* **wife very much.**
3. The pronoun refers to something outside the sentence, which is female:

   > Barbara ist mit Claudia verheiratet, sie sind ein lesbisches Paar. Aber auch Markus liebt Claudia. Markus ist Barbaras bester Freund.
   >   **Er** *(Markus)* **liebt *ihre*** *(Barbaras)* **Frau sehr.**
   >
   > Barbara is married to Claudia, they are a lesbian couple. But also Markus loves Claudia. Markus is Barbaras best friend.
   >   **He** *(Markus)* **loves *her*** *(Barbaras)* **wife very much.**

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Therfore **Die Mutter holt ihren Sohn vom Kindergarten ab.** is *the mother take her children from the Kindergarten*, right? And here do  **ihre** would have mean the children of somebody else?

Comment: My English is not the best, but I think it should be: »***T**he mother take**s** her **son** from the **preschool**.*« (German »Sohn« is not »children« in English, but »son«. And German »Kindergarten« and Englisch »kindergarten« are false friends!) In this sentense »ihren« can mean exactly the same as »her« in English: Either her own son, or another women's son. It depends on context.

Comment: Note that in general the choice depends on the grammatical gender of what sein/ihr refers to: Das Mädchen liebt seine Eltern.

Answer (score 3):

"Er liebt seine Frau" basically means: "He loves *his* wife."

"Er liebt ihre Frau" means: "He loves *her* wife" 
maybe "He loves *your* wife" (This would be more formal, so you should write "Ihre")

So it depends on what you want to say.

Comment: I would translate 2nd sentence to "He loves her wife", which is somewhat unlikely requiring a same-sex marriage. But it is still more likely, than the formal addressing in lowercase.

Comment: Okay the second sentence is not what I was looking for, thanks! Therfore **Die Mutter holt ihren Sohn vom Kindergarten ab.** is *the mother take her children from the Kindergarten*, right? And here **ihre** means the children of somebody else?