# ihr vs sein (possessive pronouns)

Tags: possessive-pronoun, possessive

I have a simple question concerning the following sentences:

> Die Katze trinkt ihr Wasser.

and

> Der Hund trinkt sein Wasser.

I would like to get a better understanding as to why "ihr" and "sein" are used the way the are. Are they interchangeable or is there a particular reason they are used in this way?

Comment: *Katze* is feminine, *Hund* is masculine.

Comment: A somewhat similar question: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/32380/when-to-use-sein-or-ihr

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use sein or ihr?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/32380/when-to-use-sein-or-ihr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In German, the choice of the **possessive article** in the third person *(sein, ihr)* depends on the gender of the noun it is referring to. In your examples, the possessive articles refer back to the subject and the gender of the noun is clearly indicated by the forms of the definite article *(der, die)*.

> **Die Katze** trinkt **ihr** Wasser. *(feminine)*
>   **Der Hund** trinkt **sein** Wasser. *(masculine)*

Note that *sein* can also refer to neuter nouns.

> **Das Huhn** trinkt **sein** Wasser. *(neuter)*

However, the **ending** of the possessive article depends on the noun that follows it.

> Die Katze mag ihr**en Kratzbaum** und der Hund mag sein**en Knochen**. *(accusative masculine*)
>   Die Katze sucht ihr**e Beute** und der Hund sucht sein**e Beute**. *(feminine)*